# Is there a way to keep up to date with Schengen border crossings being closed/controlled due to the migration crisis?

Tags: schengen, tips-and-tricks, borders, event-based-effects, land-borders

*This question is inspired by [this meta answer](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3709/10264).*

In late 2015, a number of Schengen countries introduced border controls in response to the migration crisis.

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/56150/10264) succinctly explains what these border controls do and don't mean. It's clear that there can be some interruption to travellers, but also that border controls doesn't mean a closed border.

This question is:
Which Schengen border crossings still remain controlled due to the migration crisis?
Is there a way to keep up to date on this as it changes - particularly during travels - other than trying to keep on top of any developments in the news?

Comment: I believe that there is no way other than experience. While some border crossings are tightly controlled (the Balkan Route) others are merely prepared for similar checks (the Brenner). Due to the soccer championship there are intensified border controls with the intention of stopping hooligans.

Comment: Even if this is an interesting question, I am voting to close it as too broad. It will be nearly impossible to compile a detailed documentation of the current situation at *all* internal Schengen borders and even if someone did, the information will very soon be outdated, since the situation may and will change on a day-to-day basis.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Fair enough. That is why I also asked for a way to keep up-to-date as it changes :)

Comment: @TimMalone To stay up-to-date you can visit http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/reintroduction-border-control/index_en.htm but it is somehow inaccurate since some countries just shut down their borders without noticing the EU... (like hungary and slovenia)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nigh impossible to know this without extensive *recent* experience with a specific border. Even news reports can be misleading and there is no easy way to keep up with the situation.

There is a procedure for a member state to officially notify the EU Commission that it is reintroducing border checks (cf. title III, chapter II of the Schengen Borders code), which is probably the basis for many maps and articles you will find on the net. A list of states that used the procedure is available to the public on [the official EU website](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/schengen/reintroduction-border-control/index_en.htm). But whether states did it or not does not really reflect actual practice on the ground.

For example, I have heard many direct and indirect reports from people who crossed the border between France and Italy and witnessed border checks there but, to my knowledge, France never notified the EU about it and the situation has been going on for much longer than envisioned by the regulation.

On the other hand, France did report its intent to reintroduce border checks for the Paris Climate Conference last December but even after the Paris attack that happened at the same time and the ongoing state of emergency, the checks are far from systematic.

And when states do reintroduce border checks, legally or illegally, they typically focus on specific locations, targeting sensitive borders, larger crossings or public transportation networks rather than actually staffing each and every border crossing point (many of which don't even have a building anymore). I believe many Schengen countries have reduced the size or refocused the tasks of their border police force and simply do not have the capacity to perform full border checks without seriously straining their regular police force.

Answer (score 2):

The most updated image I could find is this one: (EDIT: though it is not the most updated information you can find online)

[image: Warning: it has been made on November 12th!]

Meanings of colours:
Green = no check,
Orange = checks at their borders,
Red = borders temporarly closed

Since, this image was made (on November 12th), the terror attack in Paris happened so France should be orange : random checks at their borders. (government said it is closed but I actually go through the border with germany often and it is just a joke...)

EDIT: this map shows the exact closed / checked borders on the migrants route to Germany. It is not providing any other information about other routes (to nothern countries per example). Map has been made in March 2016.
[image]

Comment: This information seems fairly out of date. For example, some sources state that Denmark has controls, but it is green in this map. [This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schengen_Area#Current_internal_border_controls) also has useful information, though it may not be completely current.

Comment: @ZachLipton I know it ain't the most updated information. But it might be convenient for the OP to have a map, easier to read :) And the thing is on the Wikipedia article you sent, there are lot of countries missing and some inaccurate information like "During the November 2015 Paris attacks, France introduced full identity and nationality checks at its borders." as I said, it is not true. Some borders don't even have one policeman, some other have police forces but they don't check anything... Frankly, they are just creating huge traffic jams...

Comment: Nobody ever claimed the border would be "closed", see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/58807/travelling-in-out-france-after-the-attacks-of-november-2015

Comment: @Relaxed Just François Hollande (aka french president) on November, 13th... "J'ai décidé la fermeture des frontières" which can be translated as "I've decided to close the borders"

Comment: @dotixx Care to provide a source for that? Wasn't in the official transcript on the elysee website when I looked it up at the time (see the other question). Or is it just your recollection of what he said? The thing is that closing the border does not merely mean reintroducing (some) checks and it was prima facie absurd so if Hollande did say it on TV, he would have been promptly corrected by his staff and there never was any actual plan to do that.

Comment: @Relaxed Sure (sorry it's in french...): http://lelab.europe1.fr/attaques-a-paris-francois-hollande-annonce-letat-durgence-et-la-fermeture-des-frontieres-2620145 & http://www.liberation.fr/direct/element/francois-hollande-decrete-letat-durgence-national_22916/   sorry my first quote was edited by another newspaper. Original one is : "La deuxième décision que j'ai prise, c'est la fermeture des frontières" => "The second decision I took is closing the borders."

Comment: I see, I missed that so my earlier comment was obviously inaccurate. On the other hand, it's simply a case of Hollande saying something stupid on TV. It disappeared from the transcript and there never was an official plan to close the borders (because that would have been crazy). There were however much more frequent controls than I have seen in a long time, even if they were far from systematic, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @Relaxed Agreed. Or perhaps he said that to make the public opinion thinks his response to the event is appropriate. Being populist is quite common for presidents. :p

Comment: The map is confusing, as the Hungary-Slovakia border is definitely not closed.

Comment: @JonathanReez well, many information say otherwise : http://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-35760534 I even remember that a Hungarian town did a video about the police patroling to prevent migrants to go through their border... see here: https://www.rt.com/news/315917-hungary-anti-refugee-movie/

Comment: @JonathanReez oh, you meant the border between hungary and slovakia ? my bad ... however, the map is not showing which borders are closed but which country actually have closed or set up checks at their borders

Comment: Maybe use the BBC map instead? That one actually shows which borders are affected.

Comment: @JonathanReez done. But it does not provide any information about other countries than the one on the route to Germany so I also left the one I used before which shows the whole Europe.